# Firestore: Is there a function that would be related to showing a loading GIF?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I use `get` and `addSnapshotListener` to read data from my Firestore database. I know I can handle `complete/success` and `failure` events. But I didn't find the "currently retrieving data" event which I'd use to show a loading GIF image.

Of course it's not really a problem: I can show the GIF before the NoSQL request is sent to Firestore. And, then, I'd hide it as soon as the request has completed/succeeded/failed.

**However, I'd want to know if there is something recommended by the Android team and/or development community, related to this subject?** (because what I described above seems a little bit like a "tweak")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can show the GIF before the NoSQL request is sent to Firestore. And, then, I'd hide it as soon as the request has completed/succeeded/failed.

This is exactly what everyone does.  There are no additional callbacks related to the status of a database query.  The moment you make the request, it is "in progress", and it's terminated as soon as any callbacks are received.